# How do I specify a default value in a MS Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables similar to the following:

tblInvoices: `Number | Date | Customer`
tblInvDetails: `Invoice | Quantity | Rate | Description`
tblPayments: `Invoice | Date | Amount`

I have created a query called `exInvDetails` that adds an `Amount` column to `tblInvDetails`:

```
SELECT tblInvDetails.*, [tblInvDetails.Quantity]*[tblInvDetails.Rate]* AS Amount
FROM tblInvDetails;
```

I then created a query `exInvoices` to add `Total` and `Balance` columns to `tblInvoices`:

```
SELECT tblInvoices.*,
  (SELECT Sum(exInvDetails.Amount) FROM exInvDetails WHERE exInvDetails.Invoice = tblInvoices.Number) AS Total, 
  (SELECT Sum(tblPayments.Amount) FROM tblPayments WHERE tblPayments.Invoice = tblInvoices.Number) AS Payments,
  (Total-Payments) AS Balance
FROM tblInvoices;
```

If there are no corresponding payments in `tblPayments`, the fields are null instead of `0`.  Is there a way to force the resulting query to put a `0` in this column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `nz()` function, as in `nz(colName, 0)`.  This will return `colName`, unless it is null, in which case it will return the 2nd paramter (in this case, 0).

Comment: Thanks...  That's helping.  Just to clarify, I've wrapped the entire subquery using that function like so: `nz((SELECT Sum(tblPayments.Amount) FROM tblPayments WHERE tblPayments.Invoice = tblInvoices.Number), 0) AS Payments`  Is that what you had intended?

Comment: You could also just wrap the `sum` itself in `nz()`, but the end result is probably exactly the same so it's not worth worry about.

Comment: That makes sense, and it's a little easier to read: `(SELECT nz(Sum(tblPayments.Amount), 0) FROM tblPayments WHERE tblPayments.Invoice = tblInvoices.Number) AS Payments`  Thanks!

Comment: I could be wrong, but wouldn't Sum(Nz(tblPayments.Amount, 0)) make more sense? That is, convert Null to 0 before summing? I'm not sure if it matters or if it even works (since Nz() doesn't always return the right data type, though a string "0" will likely be implicitly coerced to numeric), but that seems logically the proper way to do it (to me). Not sure it matters one bit, though.

Comment: @David - the problem is that the `sum()` itself is returning null because no rows are matches, there aren't any `tblPayments.Amount` to run `nz()` on.

Comment: I wasn't reading the SQL carefully -- it's a correlated subquery, and I was misreading it as an INNER join on two tables. So, yes, it has to be done on the Sum().

Answer (score 1):

I think that Default Value likes `Field` location. For example, My Field is `ID` that is in `tblEmpPCs` table, I used a criteria below.

```
IIf([Forms]![frmSearchByEmp]![cboTurul]="ID",[forms]![frmSearchByEmp]![Ezemshigch],[tblEmpPCs].[ID])
```

There are False value is Default value of Criteria.

[image: Query Criteria Default Value in IIf function]

I uploaded a picture of my query criteria. It may help you.